# Regex value from input field

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a `$html` variable containing a lot of html code and I'm trying to extract the value from a certain parameter (this can be the value, or the class, etc.) out of an input field based on its id.

An example of the code I'm trying to find:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled" />
```

I'm trying to build a regex that extracts the value (`fname.lname@gmail.com`) out of it, by telling it to find the value out of all `<input>` where `id="emailaddress"` - with wildcards between input and id, and between id and value (the only thing for sure is that input is before id which is before value).

Here is my current PHP code (using preg_match_all because it's supposed to become a function I can reuse in cases where there are several fields):

```
$pattern = '<input(.*)id="emailaddress"(.*)value="(.*?)"';
preg_match_all('/'.$pattern.'/si',$html,$matches);
```

I've been trying variations but I either get the first input field or no match. Any help welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be a rather simple one

```
$string = '<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled" />';

$pattern = '/<input(.*?)id=\"emailaddress\"(.*)value=\"(.*?)\"/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

That gives me:

```
array (size=4)
    0 => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string '<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com"' (length=126)
    1 => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string ' type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" ' (length=58)
    2 => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string ' maxlength="60" ' (length=16)
    3 => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string 'fname.lname@gmail.com' (length=21)
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to include the id="emailaddress" as I am searching through $html which contains many input fields and I need to restrict it to the right input field. Also is it possible to only get the value field returned in $matches instead of several rows?

Comment: Just edited the answer to search for the id="emailaddress" value. Should be good now. The way this pattern and preg_match works, is every () pattern you see will be one of the array indexes. In this case, You will always say $matches[index][3] is the email address.

Comment: Yep that works now - the only improvement would be the fact that $matches contains 5 rows, only one of them being the value itself so I'd need to loop through them all and only select the one that has a '@' and no '"'. Is it possible to make it so only the value is returned in matches?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get only the value try this:

```
$string = '<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled" />';

$pattern = '/<input(?:.*?)id=\"emailaddress\"(?:.*)value=\"([^"]+).*>/i';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump( $matches[1] );
```